# Removing last few lines in a console?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm coding a sort of terminal-styled application in C# and I've decided to go with a Console Application, I'll explain my issue and then how I want to fix it.

It's really hard to explain the issue in writing, and as they say, a picture paints a thousand words. So I've opted for showing you an image of my console application instead of explaining it, although I have tried to explain it in words below.

[image]

Okay, now for explaining it writing,

My console application has a structure similar to this:

```
admin@lawna $ some command

{}: some response

admin@lawna $ some command

{}: some response

admin@lawna $ some command

{}: some response
```

Each command I type, I expect a response from. Now, this isue is, I want to be able to tell them things without them just typing a command, I thought of a "notifications" command and it would show all the recent logging messages, but come on.. who wants to do that? Even I know that would be a terrible idea, and the end-user would hate it.

I need to be able to post logging messages, but if I post one I've still got that horrible "admin@lawna $ " message that just looks bad because I haven't even typed anything, is there a way to call a method that removes the last 2 lines, and then appends a response onto the one from the last command?

Even better, put a line after the last response, then put the logging message. I have got a method to print the "admin@lawna $ " message already, shown below.

```
public static void PrintDefault(bool afterClean)
{
    if (afterClean)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Name: " + Program.Server.ServerName);
        Console.WriteLine("  Author: " + Program.Server.ServerAuthor);
        Console.WriteLine("  Version: version " + Program.Server.ServerVersion);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.Write("  " + Environment.UserName.ToLower() + "@lawna ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    Console.Write("$ ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
```

Comment: If that answer is not enough - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+remove+previous+line+console

Comment: You can set the position in the console. Simply move it back as necessary and overwrite.